# Glob to files with suffixes within a numeric range

Tags: shell, du

I have a list of files with the following names:

```
document1
document2
document3
..
document41
document42
document43
```

To check all the all document space, I could use du -sh file*.
I am trying to access documents from document1 to document 10. I tried the following:

`du -sh document[1-10]`

But it returns `document 28` and `document 15`. I would like to know how could I access a range of files with document name from document1 to document10?

Comment: What shell are you using? Bash?

Comment: `[1-10]` is not a pattern matching the numbers 1 though 10; it matches exactly one character in either in the range `1-1` (i.e., `1`) or `0`. (Compare `zsh`, which provides `<1-10>` to do what you are looking for.)

Comment: In `bash`, you can use brace expansion instead of pathname expansion: `du -sh document{1..10}`.

Comment: yeah im using bash. Thanks @chepner for the solution

Comment: Say that I used this command, du -sh document{1..10} and there is a missing document within the range but it is not known to me which is missing.  
May i know whether there is a method to bypass reading documents that are missing in the range?

Comment: There is not. Brace expansion doesn't actually know about the files; it's purely a textual expansion to provide arguments. Pathname expansion, on the other hand, actually stats the file system to see what names are available to match the given pattern.

Comment: If you want to enable the `extglob` option, you can use a glob language that is equivalent in power to regular expressions, and write `document@([:digit:]|10)` (which matches `document` followed by either a single digit or the literal text 10).

Answer (score 2):

If [dan's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72734971/4957508) is too much to type or remember, you could use [bash's brace expansion feature](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion) to create the ten filenames, then drop `du`'s potential error messages about missing files by redirecting stderr to /dev/null:

```bash
du -sk document{1..10} 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

In bash:

```
shopt -s nullglob
du -sh document[1-9] document1[0]
```

Only existing files numbered 1-10 will be passed to `du`.

Regular sh doesn't have nullglob. If a pattern doesn't match, it's passed literally. This causes either a file not found error, or importantly, a non matching file to be passed (ie. an existing file literally named `document1[0]`).

Comment: The `[0]` is a non-obviously important piece here: it creates a "glob" expansion to the straightforward "10", but if the corresponding filename doesn't exist, it is silently removed due to `nullglob`. Just in case anyone else was wondering why you'd use `document1[0]` instead of the obvious interpretation of `document10` in this case.